# Быстрый поиск в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, search

На руках массив такого содержания:

```
Array (
[show] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Добрый динозавр
                [id] => 3777
                [alias] => dobrii-dinozavr-the-good-dinosaur
             )
    [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Звёздные войны: Пробуждение силы
                [id] => 3821
                [alias] => zvezdnie-voini-probuzhdenie-sili-star-wars-the-force-awakens

            )
    [2] и так далее...
```

Подскажите как оптимальнее всего получить `[id]` если есть только `[alias]`?

Comment: если массив из БД то можно сделать запрос туда

Comment: массив со стороннего ресурса через api

Comment: тогда кроме перебора циклом foreach в голову ничего не приходит. Еще варант писать данные в свою базу и синхронизировать периодически

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для php>5.5.0 по идее можно написать так:

```
$key = array_search("dobrii-dinozavr-the-good-dinosaur", array_column($arr, 'alias'));
echo $arr[$key]["id"];
```

Для общего случая и возможно и для 5.5.0 быстрее будет работать - постоить заранее массив с индексами по `alias` и содержимым - `id`.

Если же доставать надо разные поля, исходя из алиасов - то построить массив с ключами по `alias` и значениями - номерами в исходном массиве. Т.е. что то в этом роде:

```
<?php
$arr=array(array ("name" => "Добрый динозавр","id" => 3777,"alias" => "dobrii-dinozavr-the-good-dinosaur"),
           array ("name" => "Звёздные войны: Пробуждение силы","id" => 3821,
                "alias" => "zvezdnie-voini-probuzhdenie-sili-star-wars-the-force-awakens")
          );
$index=array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v)
{
 $index[$v['alias']]=$k;
}
print $arr[$index["dobrii-dinozavr-the-good-dinosaur"]]["id"];
?>
```

Если поиск происходит часто во многих вызовах скрипта, а получение нового исходного массива - редко. То записать информацию в БД или хотя бы заранее подготовить индексный или преобразованный массив и положить его куда нибудь, например с помощью `serialize`.